# joining a SQL table with no value

Tags: mysql

I am doing a table join

```
SELECT b.type AS business, 
       b.business AS business,
       b.city AS city 
FROM businesses as b 
   JOIN cities AS c ON n.city = c.id;
```

My problem is that my table looks like this:

```
id    type   business    city
 1     1       2           4
 2     4       5           2
 3     2       3           0
```

So sometimes the rows will have the value of city as 0. However, with the table join if the city=0, id 3 would not be shown in the results. As there is no city id of 0. Is there a way to rectify this using SQL?

Comment: Use an outer join.  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for more information.

Comment: Incidentally, you should really use `NULL` in this case rather than `0`—then you can configure MySQL to enforce referential integrity constraints.

Answer (score 1):

As eggyal suggested, your query could look something like this:

```
SELECT b.type AS business, 
       b.business AS business,
       CASE WHEN c.city IS  NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE c.city END AS city 
FROM businesses as b 
  LEFT JOIN cities AS c ON b.city = c.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a CASE statement works but I think [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is a little cleaner.

```
SELECT b.type AS business, 
       b.business AS business,
       COALESCE(c.city,'N/A') AS city 
FROM businesses as b 
  LEFT JOIN cities AS c ON b.city = c.id;
```

As eggyal said, it's best to use `NULL` values but if you're stuck using zeros you could add a [NULLIF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)

```
SELECT b.type AS business, 
       b.business AS business,
       COALESCE(NULLIF(c.city,0),'N/A') AS city 
FROM businesses as b 
  LEFT JOIN cities AS c ON b.city = c.id;
```

Comment: I should be using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER?

Comment: The reason to prefer `NULL` over `0` is so that MySQL can enforce referential integrity constraints.  `NULLIF()` does not assist with that.

Comment: @eggyal I totally agree. I just wanted to give an option within the bounds of the original question (using zero).

Comment: @user1925900, yes as eggyal mentioned in his comment to your question you should use NULLs rather than zeros and use a LEFT JOIN (see the link in his comment above).